# What's the best way to setState in reactJS using antD <Collapse> with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to update the selectedQuestion(question.id) variable using setSelectedQuestion(question.id) within collapse, but the value for question is local to the questions.map(). I'm looking to see if there's a way to bring that value up, or if there's a better way to approach the problem.

Things to note: antd Panel's can't onClick / onChange, I need the accordian prop to work so I can't map each question into the

```
          {selectedCategory && <Collapse onChange={() => {setSelectedQuestion(question.id)
            fetchAnswersForQuestion(question.id)}} accordion>
            {questions && questions.map((question, index) => {
              return <Panel key={index}>
                <List
                  size="small"
                  // header={<div className={'font-bold'}>Answers List</div>}
                  footer={<div>
                      <input value={newAnswer} onChange={(ev) => {
                          setNewAnswer(ev.currentTarget.value);
                      }} type="text" className={'border p-1 mr-5 w-2/3'}/>
                      <button type={'button'} onClick={createNewAnswer} className={'btn btn-success'}>Add Answer</button>
                  </div>}
                  bordered
                  dataSource={question.Answers}
                  renderItem={answer => <List.Item>
                      <div>
                          {answer.answerTxt}
                      </div>

                  </List.Item>}
                  />
              </Panel>
            })}
          </Collapse>}
```

new to stack overflow, hope this was enough / relevant info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChange` function has a `key` parameter which you can use. You need to set the Panel's `key` to `question.id` instead of `index` and change the `onChange` function to `(key) => setSelectedQuestion(key)`

Comment: tyty, mission accomplished